# Concatenation of file's name in the path : HIVE

Tags: concatenation, hiveql

When I run the query bellow, it works: (Because I put the name of file in hard )

```
LOAD DATA  INPATH  '/user/test20170209.csv' INTO TABLE table1
```

I want to launch this query every day with the current day but I don't know how we do the concatenation in the path.

```
LOAD DATA INPATH  '/user/test'+FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(),'yyyyMMdd')+.csv' 
INTO TABLE table1
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Not sure whether this solves it all, but you seem to miss a quote before .csv